# Switch between Buttons - Image cannot be displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want the image background of the button to change when the user clicks on it.
I made a class containig different attributes to switch between the images based on their class. 
I use this method:

HTML:

```
     <span id="play"></span>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#play').click(function(){

    $(this).toggleClass("#pause");
    });
    });
```

CSS:

```
    #play
    {
   width:100px;
   height:60px;
   background-image: url('18.jpg');
   float:left;
    }
   #pause
   {
  width:100px;
  height:60px;
  background-image: url('19.jpg');
  float:left;
   }
```

But the image isn't displayed at all, neither when before I click on the button,  nor after it, do you know why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `#pause` is not the name of a css class but an id.

You should have something like this

HTML:

```
     <span id="play" class="play"></span>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#play').click(function(){                             
            $(this).toggleClass("pause");
            $(this).toggleClass("play");
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
.play
{
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    background-image: url('18.jpg');
    float:left;
}
.pause
{
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    background-image: url('19.jpg');
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `#` is used to denote an `id`, yet you're toggling a class. Try this:

```
$('#play').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("pause");
});
```

```css
.pause {
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    background-image: url('19.jpg');
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of the function is toggleClass. Which toggles a class, you're using ID's.

HTML

```
 <span class="play"></span>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.play').click(function(){

        $(this).toggleClass("pause"); //lose the #
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.play {
   width:100px;
   height:60px;
   background-image: url('18.jpg');
   float:left;
 }

 .pause {
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    background-image: url('19.jpg');
    float:left;
 }
```